# Dropzone.js init function() not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have this HTML:

```
<div id='drop_zone'>
  <div class="close_button" id="removeAllImages">Remove All</div>
  <form action="PHP/uploads.php" class="dropzone" id='fbDropZone'></form>
</div>
```

and this Javascript in the `$(document).ready(function() {}`

```
window.Dropzone;
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$('#fbDropZone').dropzone = {
    init: function() {
     fbDropZone = this;
     $("#removeAllImages").click(function(){fbDropZone.removeAllFiles();})
    },
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 5,
    maxFiles : 1,
    autoProcessQueue : false,
};
```

But the `init:function()` isn't being executed. I can turn `autoProcessQueue` to `false` or `true` and that works so I know the `fbDropZone` `id` is correct - but the `maxFiles` is ignored as well. Have I done a daft syntax error somewhere..? I'm running Safari 7.

Comment: Which Programming language you are using?

Comment: Javascript with a downloaded copy of Dropzone.js.

Answer (score 12):

It turns out that the code position is crucial: the dropzone calls have to be placed outside of the document loaded or ready function (I guess you'd call it inline).

Comment: I think you just saved me a lot of hours!

Answer (score 5):

Check that you have to `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false` outside of your `$(document).ready(...).`

Wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  $("#mydropzone").dropzone({
    init: function() {...}
   );
});
```

Right:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mydropzone").dropzone({
    init: function() {...}
   );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$("#mydropzone").dropzone({
    init: function() {
        var $this = this;
        $("button#clear-dropzone").click(function() {
            $this.removeAllFiles(true);
        });
    },
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 5,
    maxFiles : 1,
    autoProcessQueue : false
});
```